# Pandas pivot heatmap filter most frequent values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, heatmap, melt

Basically, my final result should be a heatmap of the `X` most preferred destinations by the `X` most common origin countries (like R question [How to create heatmap only for 50 highest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60671461/how-to-create-heatmap-only-for-50-highest-value) here). Let's say `x=2` to align with the small toy dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'destination_1': ['Germany', 'France', 'UK', 'India', 'China'],
                   'destination_2': ['China', 'Vietnam', 'Namibia', 'India', 'UK'],
                   'destination_3' : ['France', 'Italy', 'Namibia', 'China', 'UK'],
                   'origin' : ['Germany', 'US', 'UK', 'China', 'UK']})
```

The destination count should be based on the mention across all three destination variables. To account for this, I melt and pivot the data.

```
 df1 = df.melt(id_vars= ['origin'],
    value_vars= ['destination_1', 'destination_2', 'destination_3'], var_name='columns')
df_heatmap = df1.pivot_table(index='origin',columns='value',aggfunc='count')
```

`df_heatmap` is basically already a heatmap, no problem visualizing it. The only problem for me is I don't get where/how I can put a filter to keep only the `x` most common origins and destinations.

Answer (score 0):

Would surely be better to filter the pivot table to get the true "totals", but here's a way that at least gets the `x:x` pivot table dimension. Basically I use lists of top value counts in both dimensions to filter the dataframe before pivoting it.

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars= ['origin'],
    value_vars= ['destination_1', 'destination_2', 'destination_3'],
    var_name='columns')

most = df1['origin'].value_counts()[:2].index.tolist()
most2 = df1['value'].value_counts()[:2].index.tolist()
filt = (df1['origin'].isin(most) & df1['value'].isin(most2))
df2 = df1[filt]

df_heatmap = df2.pivot_table(index='origin',columns='value',aggfunc='count', margins = True, margins_name='Total')
```